# How do I stop Visual Studio Code (VSCode) from linting new, unsaved files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

In Visual Studio Code (VSCode), I often want to temporarily store some text while coding. A quick way to do this is to hit Ctrl + N (to open a new file in a new tab) and then Ctrl + V (to paste the text). I can then go back to the new tab later on and retrieve the text. This is safer than using the clipboard, because I don't want to accidentally blow it away by copying something else.

However, the ESLint extension for VSCode will automatically detect that I have pasted some JavaScript code into a new file and will immediately start linting it, even though it is a brand new & unsaved file. This clutters up the "Problems" pane with spurious errors.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I need it for Quokka files.

Answer (score -1):

Search preferences for "Format on paste" or in `settings.json` enter:

```
"editor.formatOnPaste": true
```

Comment: This has no effect.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to click on the language icon in the bottom right hand corner, and switch it to `Plain Text (plaintext)`.

This will obviously disable the linter, because it won't be a JavaScript/TypeScript file anymore.

It's also probably possible to make a VSCode hotkey that will do this in one keystroke, but I don't really do this pattern often enough to justify making a custom hotkey for it.

Comment: This worked for me, I was trying to paste minified css and vscode kept formatting the spaces back in. Changing it to plain text allowed me to paste and save the *.min.css and it did not get molested into shape by the linter.

Comment: Yeah, that's not really a solution... it's rather handy to have syntax highlighting even though I DO NOT want lint "errors"...